# Count digits as separate words using str_word_count in PHP

Tags: php, string, word-count

I am trying to use `str_word_count` to count the number of words in a message.

```
$wordcount = str_word_count($message,0,'0123456789');
```

I can pretty much be guaranteed that there will just be words, numbers, and spaces in there. The message is the result of an encoded speech to text message.

One thing I am struggling with is getting it to properly return the right number of words. I need each digit to be counted as its own word. Thus "4 5 6" is 3 words and "456" is also 3 words. "FOUR" is one word and "FOUR 44" is 3 words, etc.

The [documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-word-count.php) for this function says I ought to be able to do this by specifying characters to count as words as the third argument, which I have done. However, an entire "block" of digits is still counted as *only* one word. I tried adding spaces between the digits but that visually triggered a syntax error in Notepad++ *and* blew up my whole PHP page, basically.

I thought about filtering the string for digits and then adding its length to the word count, but then I am double counting some digits for sure... and that's just messy!

Is there *any* way I can do this natively with `str_word_count`?

Comment: Is it possible to get a word that looks like `1two3`?

Comment: @Nick In my case, no. I don't know what I would want to happen then because that's not in the criteria. The input is the result of speech to text conversion, so getting "1two3" would be all but impossible anyhow!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to work around this is to use [`preg_replace`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) first to split your strings of digits into individual digits, and then count the words. For example:

```
$message = "I have 123 chickens";
$message = preg_replace('/\s*(\d)/', ' $1', $message);
$wordcount = str_word_count($message, 0, '0123456789');
echo $wordcount;
```

Output

```
6
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/e203X)

Comment: This solution outputs 5 if the string is "I have 1two3 chickens" when it should output 6.

Comment: @parsonsbots there's no indication in OPs question that `1two3` is a valid word (they mention words, numbers and spaces, and typically words means sequences of letters, not something like 1two3). It seems a bit harsh to downvote based on a possible scenario which isn't mentioned in the question.

Comment: "The message is the result of an encoded speech to text message." - 1zero1 could be a possible output for 101 in a rough speech to text encoding, but I'll remove the downvote (once the hourly limitation is removed).

Comment: @parsonsbots The STT I am using hasn't done that. I have pre-processing that is done before that goes to the main server, also.

Answer (score 1):

```
$message = 'Hello 012THREE4five6';
echo str_word_count(preg_replace('/[0-9]/', ' zzz ', $message));
```